# To Count the occurrence of pattern between specific values in Oracle table

Tags: mysql, oracle, count

For example, with the help of below tables,

```
Rn  ID Pattern
1   C20
2   C21
3   C25
4   C25
5   C25
6   C25
7   C25
8   C21
9   C23
10  C20
11  C21
12  C25
13  C25
14  C25
15  C22
16  C21
17  C20
```

I want to count the `C25` pattern between each `C20`.

The result should be like,

-->Count of `C25` b/n 1st and 2nd occurrence of `C20` = 5
see below reference

```
Rn  ID Pattern
1   C20
2   C21
3   C25
4   C25
5   C25
6   C25
7   C25
8   C21
9   C23
10  C20
```

--> Count of `C25` b/n 2nd and 3rd occurrence of `C20` = 3

```
10  C20
11  C21
12  C25
13  C25
14  C25
15  C22
16  C21
17  C20
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Oracle database? Or do you really mean `[mysql]`? Please be careful with the database tagging: answers often require syntax which is specific to a particular database product, which is likely to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LAG` analytic function with the `IGNORE NULLS` option to find the previous row at the start of your range and then use the `COUNT` analytic function with a range window to get the count:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e7f5f/16)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( rn, id ) AS
  SELECT  1,  'C20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  2,  'C21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  3,  'C25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  4,  'C25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  5,  'C25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  6,  'C25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  7,  'C25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  8,  'C21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  9,  'C23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10,  'C20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11,  'C21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 12,  'C25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 13,  'C25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14,  'C25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 15,  'C22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 16,  'C21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 17,  'C20' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( CASE id WHEN 'C25' THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( ORDER BY rn
                  ROWS BETWEEN (rn - prev_rn) PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
           AS num_c25
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           LAG( CASE id WHEN 'C20' THEN rn END, 1, 1 )
             IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY rn ) AS prev_rn
    FROM   table_name t
  ) t
)
WHERE  id = 'C20'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e7f5f/16/0)**:

```
| RN |  ID | PREV_RN | NUM_C25 |
|----|-----|---------|---------|
|  1 | C20 |       1 |       0 |
| 10 | C20 |       1 |       5 |
| 17 | C20 |      10 |       3 |
```

Another way is to use a hierarchical query:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( CASE id WHEN 'C25' THEN 1 END ) OVER ( ORDER BY rn ROWS BETWEEN LEVEL - 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS num_c25,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT rn AS start_rn,
         CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS isleaf
  FROM   table_name t
  START WITH id = 'C20'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR rn + 1 = rn
  AND   id <> 'C20'
)
WHERE isleaf = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e7f5f/16/1)**:

```
| RN |  ID | NUM_C25 | START_RN | ISLEAF |
|----|-----|---------|----------|--------|
|  9 | C23 |       5 |        1 |      1 |
| 16 | C21 |       3 |       10 |      1 |
| 17 | C20 |       0 |       17 |      1 |
```